# why aren't x-axis values labeld correctly on this plotly js chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly

As far as I can tell, my chart is pretty close to the example of a bar graph in the official documentation:

```
var data = [ { "type": "bar", "x": [ "<=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6 - 10", "11 - 20", "21+" ], "y": [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 30 ], "textposition": "auto", "hoverinfo": "x+y", "marker": { "color": "#B5C6D6" } } ];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

html

```
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

However, the x axis values are not what I entered into my x-axis array.  Instead of 1, 2, 3, ... 21+, I get 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.  I have no idea where these values are coming from.

https://codepen.io/dvdgdnjsph/pen/BaKwRKm?editable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fplotly.com%2Fjavascript%2Fbar-charts%2F

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that your x-axis is categorical. You can do this by creating a `layout` object and passing it into the `newPlot()` function:

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Example using your code:

```js
var data = [{
  "type": "bar",
  "x": ["<=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6 - 10", "11 - 20", "21+"],
  "y": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 30],
  "textposition": "auto",
  "hoverinfo": "x+y",
  "marker": {
    "color": "#B5C6D6"
  }
}];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

<div id='myDiv'>
  <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
</div>
```